# Instagram возвращает в ответ непонятную кодировку, как исправить?

Tags: java, curl, instagram, okhttp

Имеется собственно написанная библиотека для обращения к web api instagram.
Логин проходит, получаю все csrf и mid токены, далее пытаюсь получить список подписчиков, выполняя запрос:

```
JsonObject variables = new JsonObject();
    variables.addProperty("id", this.userId);
    variables.addProperty("first", 20);
    HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("https")
            .host("www.instagram.com")
            .addPathSegment("graphql")
            .addPathSegment("query")
            .addQueryParameter("query_id", "17851374694183129")
            .addQueryParameter("variables", variables.toString())
            .build();
```

В ответ получаю:

```
�5�*>�5"֑�,���Z#�
��Ȓ�e}ք��l�UX��E��5i�͘�)�R��T���~썔|?�̰�ewF����{X;<��A�bB�(�!`A�b�J^
��BNI�Q�Bd��XG&�Y�E�\���2o����S�it"`W�[T�04O�=�$�%X����"������f#)KG���c�
쀽:D ��UAY�{cQ��yl����bY.�eYn�U���
u]�g������  ��
��%/���� ����{P!�=�9ftbdk��2�u�Uݕ^��o�K��9}Se��S9jogfY�ҷ�{��?՚4ޒ
��HȋW�*���P��x\*�d�9�Q��[�κ��ћ��萫D�iN��o��,-kS��G$v��}C7�Ô���(�"�    
l��0�8fpb�����C��_"z��*_��}�u1��/#ul�
```

В запросе всё идентично web-версии, однако раскодировать получаемое сообщение не получается.
В заголовках отправлю:

```
Request.Builder request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .header("referer","https://www.instagram.com/")
            .get();
    request.addHeader("accept","*/*");
    request.addHeader("accept-language","ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
    request.addHeader("accept-encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
    request.addHeader("cookie",cookie);
    request.addHeader("user-agent",Constants.USER_AGENT);
    request.addHeader("x-requested-with","XMLHttpRequest");
```

При этом ответ от сервера 200, сообщение "ОК".

Comment: А если добавить что-то типа `request.addHeader("accept-charset","utf-8");`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб буду дома - попробую. Смотрел по режиму разработчиков Chrome, он таких заголовок не отправляет.

Comment: Скорее всего это gzip. Вы же в заголовках указали, что поддерживается gzip, вот инстаграм его и шлёт

Comment: @andreymal остальные ответы приходят без всяких кодировок. Там тоже gzip указан.

Comment: @PirateNinja значит сервер по остальным ссылкам не хочет присылать gzip - его право. Просто уберите accept-encoding, оставив всё остальное, и всё должно заработать

Comment: @andreymal всё уже заработало. Просто перестал отправлять токены в заголовках.

Comment: @PirateNinja затыкание проблемы без попыток разобраться в истинной причине — так себе идея

Answer (score 1):

Ситуация достаточно странная, однако всё заработало после того, как я перестал отправлять в заголовках токены. В заголовке остался только referer  и куки.

Comment: @0xdb, эм, вы бот? Тогда у вас баг :)

Comment: @Flippy Вы о чём?

Comment: @0xdb, ответ как раз исчерпывающий..

Comment: @Flippy  Возможно,  но у меня другое мнение.

Comment: @0xdb ну ответ как раз исчерпывающий: перестаю отправлять заголовки, отправляю только куки, всё заработало.

Comment: @0xdb вы пытаетесь создать проблему из ничего. Два человека вам уже пояснили, что ответ решает проблему, является доходчивым, а так же вполне исчерпывающим. Instagram не даёт никакого пояснения к api на веб морде, соответственно, 100% пояснения и концов не найти, чисто исследовательская часть. В ходе работы которой появилось проблема и была так же решена.

Comment: @PirateNinja ваш ответ не содержит информации, *почему* неотправка заголовков решает проблему, так что он не такой уж и исчерпывающий :)

Comment: @PirateNinja Вам тоже уже 2-а участника пояснили, что ответ не является исчерпывающим. Добавте хотя бы в ответ пример рабочего кода.